CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED when require_client_auth=True is set in python grpc server
When setting up an grpc server with mTLS it's not possible for me to authenticate the client certificate.
My setup consists of a selfsigned root CA which signed the server certificate and a subordinary CA which signs the certificates for the client.
I initialized the server credentials as followed:
server_credentials = grpc.ssl_server_credentials(
    [(
        server_key, # key of server cert
        server_cert, # server cert (signed by root CA)
    )],
    root_certificates=ca_cert, # cert of sub CA
    require_client_auth=True
)

I'm trying to send a request with grpcurl
grpcurl --cacert certs/root.crt -cert certs/client.crt -key certs/client.key example.com:8086 list

which returns the following error:
Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED.
handshake_manager 0x7f1718022110: error=UNKNOWN:Ssl handshake failed: SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED {tsi_code:10, tsi_error:"TSI_PROTOCOL_FAILURE", created_time:"2024-04-16T08:19:04.830816282+00:00"} shutdown=0 index=1, args={endpoint=(nil), args={}, read_buffer=(nil) (length=0), exit_early=0}
handshake_manager 0x7f1718022110: handshaking complete -- scheduling on_handshake_done with error=UNKNOWN:Ssl handshake failed: SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED {tsi_code:10, tsi_error:"TSI_PROTOCOL_FAILURE", created_time:"2024-04-16T08:19:04.830816282+00:00"}

However, when checking the certificates via openssl, everything is verifies successful. Also, removing the root_certificates and require_client_auth parameter from the function leads to a successful connection.
Any ideas?

The solution for me was to add a subjectAlternativeName entry to the certificate. It seems that this is required for a successful verification in grpc but not in openssl.
An example config file could look like this:
[ req ]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions     = v3_req

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName            = AB
stateOrProvinceName    = CD
localityName           = EFG_HIJ
organizationName       = MyOrg
organizationalUnitName = MyOrgUnit
commonName             = mycommname.com
emailAddress           = emailaddress@myemail.com

[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
subjectAltName   = DNS:client.example.com

